# Is running possible in Dead Space 3?

Tags: dead-space-3

Is there a way to run in dead space? The game doesn't list control schematics at all, kinda dumb.

Answer (score 4):

On xbox/PS controller the left trigger is the run/sprint.

On PC it is hold down shift.